# How to use a music font to display sheet music on an android tablet

Tags: android, fonts

I am working on an android tablet app for displaying sheet music giving it some basic editing and playing capabilities.

My first hurdle is how to display the music in the first place.

The majority of desktop apps use music fonts, which makes zooming and resizing quite "simple".  However, it would appear that I would need to be able to access the individual glyphs to do this - which is not possible in android as far as I understand.

Should I stick with a music font and try to find a way to get the information needed ?
Should I abandon this and be looking at using svg files or transparent PNGs ?

Can anyone advise here, please ?